# How can I force alsa to always "unmute" the Headphone Jack Sense?

Tags: 11.10, laptop, hp, alsa

I've got a HP nc8000 (my secondary laptop now), and it's got some quirks. One of the most annoying is that I have to remember to "unmute" the Headphone Jack Sense every time I boot.

**P.S: Audio info:**

**Card:** Intel 82801DB-ICH4
**Chip:** Analog Devices AD1981B

Is there a way to make this be the default setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by an update to Pulseaudio and ALSA.